# Using merge to detect differences in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am using merge to join two data frames together.  The 2 data frames are data from a database table over two different dates.  *I need to work out what changed*.  The number of rows will be different, but I just to join the newer data set to the older data set with an inner join, and see what changed.

At the moment, I am taking advantage of the `_x` and `_y` naming of the data frames, and the `.columns` data to let me *compare the fields for differences after the merge*.

There must be an easier way to do this.  I did try to use the new `compare()` method of 1.1.0, but it doesnt seem to like frames with a different shape (i.e. rows in my case), rendering it useless to me.

```
def get_changed_records(df_old, df_new, file_info):

    join_keys = file_info["compare_col"].split(",");
    old_file_name = file_info["old_file_name"]
    new_file_name = file_info["new_file_name"]

    print("Changed Records: JOIN DATA FRAMES ON COLUMNS: previous file ", old_file_name, " current_file_name ", " new file name ", new_file_name)

    columns = df_new.columns


    df_merged = df_new.merge(df_old, how='inner', on=join_keys, indicator=True)

    changed_records = []

    for idx, row in df_merged.iterrows():
        changes = []

        for col in columns:

            if col not in join_keys:
                after_col = col + '_x';
                before_col = col + '_y';
            else:
                after_col = col
                before_col = col

            after_val = row[after_col];
            before_val = row[before_col];

            changed = False

            if pd.isnull(before_val) or pd.isnull(after_val):

                if pd.isnull(before_val) == False and pd.isnull(after_val) == True:
                    changed = True;

                if pd.isnull(before_val) == True and pd.isnull(after_val) == False:
                    changed = True;

                if pd.isnull(before_val) == True and pd.isnull(after_val) == True:
                    changed = False;

            elif after_val != before_val:
                print("COLUMN_CHANGE: ", col, " before ", before_val, " after ", after_val);
                changed = True;

            if changed == True:
                print('-' * 50);
                print('-Adding changes to result...')

                changes.append(['COLUMN_CHANGE', col, before_val, after_val, row, join_keys]);
                print(changes);

        if len(changes) > 0:
            changed_records.append(changes);
            print("changed records ", len(changed_records));
            print(changed_records);

    return changed_records
```

Comment: I would recommend something like: `pd.merge(left, right, how='right'` that will show you the rows with excessive values. Check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging) for more

Comment: I am not sure any of those examples give me a cell by cell breakdown of differences, with a before and after view of each changed cell

Comment: Ignore my comment, I now saw that you are indeed trying inner_joins. Do you think you could add a few mock data, for someone to try give an suitable answer?